# Why is Chrome the only major browser that supports printing to PDF?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, pdf, internet-explorer

Chrome has had the ability to print a webpage to a PDF for quite a while now. Why is it that the other 2 major browsers have not followed suit?

Is it because of...

- licensing
- technological hurdle
- not enough interest
- something else

?

Comment: This is not a computer problem, nor practically answerable.  Voting to close.

Comment: It's a question about browser software. Is superuser not the right place?

Comment: IMO It's not a question about a computer problem, it's question about why browser authors chose to do something a certain way. Who knows, and it's off-topic. :)

Comment: Given that some browser development happens in the open, I figure there may be records / there may be someone knowledgeable enough to know why these decisions were made. If it's a technical issue that's preventing Printing to PDF then it's definitely a computer problem.

Comment: Besides you have to admit that Superuser's description is pretty vague: "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users"

Comment: I understand you point. But see here for some ideas on what not to ask: http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

It's about whether or not the product team sees implementation and support of PDF printing as having a sufficiently low cost/benefit (or high benefit/cost) ratio to be worth the opportunity cost of not implementing some other feature.

Counter-examples to licensing and technology being the hurdles would be that Opera and Firefox can print to PDF. Firefox needs an  [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-pages-to-pdf/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, Google must have chosen to implement the necessary writing to PDF format (or embed an third-party implementation into Chrome) while the other browser makers have not -- and possible would prefer (in the case of Microsoft), that we buy something or that we use another format like MS's XPS format.
So I would say: commercial decision.

Comment: Does Microsoft make money off of XPS? Does anyone use it? I don't think I've ever once used it or been asked to use it. "Commercial decision" may be roughly equivalent to "Not enough customer interest"?

Comment: XPS was Microsoft attempting to high-stick Adobe PDF and failing laughably. "Commercial decision" means anything management thinks relates to the corporate mission. Usually interpreted to mean profit, although not always.